# Python check list items for a string

Tags: python

The problem is the following, for instance:

```
lst = ['2456', '1871', '187']

d = {
    '1871': '1',
    '2456': '0',
}

for i in lst:
    if any(i in x for x in d.keys()):
        print i

% python test.py
2456
1871
187
```

So, I need to get all the elements from the list "lst" that are contained in the keys of dictionary "d", without a substring match, cause if I do "print d[i]", I get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> lst = ['2456', '1871', '187']
>>> d = {
    '1871': '1',
    '2456': '0',
}
>>> [x for x in lst if x in d]
['2456', '1871']
```

Comment: Yup nice quick look up and will preserve order and duplicate entries... +1 (although if that wasn't important I s'pose the next best `set` like approach would be `d.viewkeys() & lst`)

Answer (score 1):

this line should do the job:

```
 l=[e for e in d if e in lst]
```

with your data:

```
In [5]: l=[e for e in d if e in lst]

In [6]: l
Out[7]: ['2456', '1871']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`sets`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
lst = ['2456', '1871', '187']
d = {'1871': '1', '2456': '0'}

print(set(lst) & set(d.keys())) # prints '{'2456', '1871'}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for i in li:
    if i in d:
        print "{0} => {1}".format(i,d[i])


2456 => 0
1871 => 1
```

In a list comprehension:

```
>>> [i for i in li if i in d]
['2456', '1871']
```